# Ken Burns Effect on actionscript3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I want to develop a zooming effect like this gallery: http://www.monoslideshow.com/
Can anyone give me a hint? I'm not sure about the math that i have to do for getting something similar
Thanks in advance

Comment: +1  For Ken Burns Effect, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_Effect

Answer (score 1):

All that is really happening in that gallery is a Tween on multiple parameters. To replicate this effect, over a few seconds, increase scaleX and scaleY a small amount and choose a random direction in which to move the image (also a small amount such that you don't move the image out of view - move it only by as much canvas space you gain from scaling).

i.e.: 200x200 image, if you Tween to scale 1.05, you would be dealing with 10 extra pixels in either direction.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please mark as your accepted answer, otherwise let me know where you need clarification and I'll be happy to assist.